# Getting error while syncdb django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_migrations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psql

I have installed postgreSQL and psycopg2, then I created a db and user, I have granted all the permission for the user to the db and I have made all the changes in `settings.py`. But while I try to migrate, I am getting the error `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_migrations`

`settings.py`:

```
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 
            'NAME': 'easyapp',
            'USER': 'krishna',
            'PASSWORD': 'sudeep',
            'HOST': 'localhost',                     
            'PORT': '',                      
        }
    }
```

Can anybody help me??

Comment: Have you given that user permission to modify the database *schema* or just permission to modify the data?

Comment: @Sayse I have give a grant privilege to the database that's it

Comment: There lies the problem then, doing a migration changes the schema and you need permission to do that

Comment: @Sayse how can i set the  permission

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-schemas.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to migrate as follows

```
python manage.py migrate auth
python manage.py migrate
```