# Django, psycopg2: permission denied on Heroku server

Tags: python, django, heroku, psql, heroku-postgres

I have a Django project running on Heroku, every time an action is carried out, I get a looong series of errors like this, all pointing back to the same cause:

```
 ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /event/
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
 psycopg2.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_session
```

The URL `/event/` does not exist on my project, nor is it referenced anywhere in it, the only database associated with it is as follows:
`DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config()}`

How can I fix this through Heroku? I tried the online console with some basic psql command, but all I got was this response

`psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory`

EDIT: I tried this line from another question but got this response:

```
heroku pg:psql default -c "GRANT ALL ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public to admin;" --remote master
 ▸    Unknown database: default. Valid options are: DATABASE_URL
```

EDIT2: Using this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39070745/6187682) with [heroku-data-explorer](https://heroku-data-explorer.herokuapp.com/#/) I managed to fix my issue, but for future reference, if someone knows of a more robust way of accessing the heroku databases, that'd be great

Comment: What do your DATABASES settings look like?

Comment: There isn't one, not that I can find. In `global_settings` the database value is empty

Comment: You should have a settings.py though.

Comment: I found this `DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config()}`