# Django + PostgreSQL backup and restore on an EC2 instance

Tags: python, django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a simple monolithic architecture:

A Django project hosted on an EC2 instance, talks to a PostgreSQL DB running on the same instance.
I chose this architecture considering the traffic and cost. So, don't bash me on this one. :)

For disaster recovery, I regularly dump my DB (a full dump `pg_dump -U postgres fishercoder_db > fishercoder_dump.sql`).

At restoring, I cannot get Django and the restoring DB to talk nicely with each other:

1. If I launch Django and run `./manage.py migrate` first, and then restore the DB from the dump, it fails because Django has already created a bunch of internal tables after running `./manage.py migrate` which have exactly the same name of in my dump;
2. If I restore the DB from the dump first, then my Django app cannot stand up because of insufficientprivilege to run `./manage.py migrate`, details asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62472371/psycopg2-errors-insufficientprivilege-permission-denied-for-relation-django-mig).

My question is:

1. Is my DR strategy reasonable? Any other more optimal ways?
2. How can I get this approach to work: restore my site on a new EC2 instance with DB restored from a .sql dump.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote my own set of utils for exactly this, as I could never fully remember the command line options necessary: https://github.com/FlipperPA/django-pg-copy

Have you tried `pg_restore` with these options?

```sh
pg_restore -c --if-exists -h localhost -U [your_django_user] -d [your_django_db]  fishercoder_dump.sql
```

You may also want to consider some additional parameters for your dump:

```sh
pg_dump -Fc -c -x ...
```

`-Fc`: custom format
`-c`: (or `--clean`): dumps a clean version, with DROPs of objects.
`-x`: skip dumping access privileges

Good luck!

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for your incredible work! I was able to dump this way and `pg_restore` as well, but I cannot run `pg_restore` using my `fishercoderuser`, instead, I had to restore using `postgres` user, but after that, when I use `fishercoderuser` to connect to my DB via a sql client, I cannot query my tables, it says `ERROR: permission denied for relation my_table`

Comment: After you restore using using `postgres`, you should be able to change the owner on the restored database. Logged in as `postgres`, `ALTER DATABASE fishercoder_db OWNER TO fishercoderuser;` Give that a whirl! :)